# Pivottable VBA Code Not Correctly Filtering Dates

Tags: sql, excel, vba, date

I'm trying to filter date to reflect only the last three months, the current month, and the next 3 months. What I'm ending up with is all dates within that range for all years. Also for some reason, it deselects the second week of March. What am I doing wrong?

Code Below

```
For Each pi In pvt.PivotFields("Week Of").PivotItems
Select Case pi.Value
    Case Is < DateSerial(Year(Now) + 1, Month(Now) - 3, Day(Now))
        pi.Visible = False

    Case pi.Value > DateSerial(Year(Now) + 1, Month(Now) + 3, Day(Now))

        pi.Visible = False

    Case Else

        pi.Visible = True

End Select
```

Comment: Silly question, but does the "Week Of" column show years too?

Comment: Another question: is pi.Value in the DateSerial format?

Comment: Yes. It does and I tried your solution and it worked...going to go back to my code and do some hard thinking. Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Case statements aren't written consistently.  The first one says:

```
Case Is < ...
```

Your second one says:

```
Case pi.Value > ...
```

I'm pretty sure the second one should also use `Case Is`.  Not sure if that will solve the issue, but I wanted to point it out.

Or you could just rewrite your code to skip the Case statements altogether:

```
iEarliest = DateSerial(Year(Now) + 1, Month(Now) - 3, Day(Now))
iLatest = DateSerial(Year(Now) + 1, Month(Now) + 3, Day(Now))
For Each pi In pvt.PivotFields("Week Of").PivotItems
    If pi.Value > iLatest or pi.Value < iEarliest then
        pi.Visible = False
    Else
        pi.Visible = True
    End if
Next
```